Setting up a random math equation generator but I'm having trouble getting it to recognize the operators properly
this is what i have so far
import random

def main():
    # making lists for question
    numList1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    numList2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    charList = (1, 2, 3, 4)
    OpChooser = random.choice(charList)

    if OpChooser == 1:
        Operator='+'
        question = random.choice(numList1), Operator, random.choice(numList2)
        print(question)
    elif OpChooser == 2:
        Operator='-'
        question = random.choice(numList1), Operator, random.choice(numList2)
        print(question)
    elif OpChooser == 3:
        Operator='//'
        question = random.choice(numList1), Operator, random.choice(numList2)
        print(question)
    elif OpChooser == 4:
        Operator ='*'
        question = random.choice(numList1), Operator, random.choice(numList2)
        print(question)

main()

Sorry everyone, i have been very unclear with my goals.
i am trying to create a math question where the terminal gives an equation and the user types in the answer. the terminal must then tell the user if the question is right or wrong.
i am struggling to:

find a way to clean up the equation and not make it look like this (5, '+', 7). (which is what the terminal currently gives me.) i want it to be easy to read for the user.

find a way for the code to recognize the 'Operator' value as a true operator (for later on when i make this interactable)


thank you for your help

What are you expecting if charList == 1: do do? charList is always ("+","-","//","*").

Try starting with operator = random.choice(charList). Then you can use if operator == "+":

thank you for pointing that out, i had made edits to the code(that still doesnt work) and forgot to change it

question = is invalid. You have assign something to the variable.

charList is still a tuple, not a number. You have to select a random element and then test that with if.

You could use a dictionary: {"+": operator.add, "-": operator.sub, "*": operator.mul, ...}

Why not just go back to the original list of strings. Then can just do Operator = random.choice(charList), you don't need all the if statements.

sorry about the mistakes i made in my edit, it should be cleaned up now. You mentioned using the dictionary, how could that work?

@norsh: The code shown is doing exactly what I expect.  Can you clarify what you mean by "cant seem to find any way to get the value to be an operator" in the question?  What specifically isn't working as expected here?  At the moment this question appears to be a wildly moving target...

@david i was unclear earlier, i have updated the post (again) to hopefully explain my problem better

Already voted to close as needs clarity, but this now also appears to be a duplicate of: Which is the preferred way to concatenate a string in Python?, Safely evaluate simple string equation  (Each of which likely has multiple other relevant duplicates as well.)

Regarding the first problem - I suggest simply not saving the question in a separate variable, but simply printing it:
Instead-
question = random.choice(numList1), Operator, random.choice(numList2)
Print (question)

Do-
print(random.choice(numList1), Operator, random.choice(numList2))

Regarding your second problem, I would suggest you first save the drawn numbers - and not draw them straight for printing, and each time in elif after printing the question - perform input from the user, and each time check whether the input is equal to the exercise. Something like this:
import random

def main():
    # making lists for question
    numList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    charList = (1, 2, 3, 4)
    OpChooser = random.choice(charList)

    if OpChooser == 1:
        Operator = '+'
        num1=int(random.choice(numList))
        num2=int(random.choice(numList))
        print(num1, Operator,num2)
        ans=int(input())
        if( num1+num2==ans):
            print('excellent')
        else:
            print('ho no')

and so on..

I changed the code, as Michael Cao pointed out, so that there is no need to make two lists of numbers.


Your random expression is composed of

A random choice of 1-10
A random choice of operator
A random choice of 1-10

You might as well just express that simply through three random.choice.
num1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
ops = ['+', '-', '*', '/']

print(random.choice(num1), random.choice(ops), random.choice(num1))

